# is it possible refresh gridview when change table in DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Refresh the Grid Automatically when table changes in the DB

like twitter and other facebook .

how to do this using any asp.net controls using c#

Answer (score 4):

Pokein(Reverse AJAX Library) can help you

1. [Doc](http://www.pokein.com/Help/Documentation.aspx)
2. [Sample project](http://www.pokein.com/Help/Samples.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use polling to check database changes if changed update page. For this you have to use `AJAX UpdatePanel Timer` controls.
If you want to do it automatically you need `socket` programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometGrid.aspx) Comet based grid control.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that checks whether database changes have been made, and then poll that function using async calls (jQuery in your View)